# how to install caldav4j using maven?

Tags: java, maven

How can I install caldav4j from central maven repository?

I've added dependency as seen below to pom file, but package is not downloaded

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.osaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>caldav4j</artifactId>
    <version>0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera this sort of question and answer is allowed and welcome by the system. It is not a reason to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunetly caldav4j is not in the central repository so you have to add external repository to your pom file. According to caldav4j [FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/caldav4j/wiki/FAQ) repository address is at: https://caldav4j.googlecode.com/svn/maven/ so here is what you should add to pom file:

```
 <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>org.osaf.caldav4j</id>
            <name>org.osaf.caldav4j</name>
            <url>https://caldav4j.googlecode.com/svn/maven/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Comment: The Maven repository is on GitHub now: https://github.com/caldav4j/maven